# Oracle PL/SQL: FETCH cursor doesn't fetch EOF !! Why?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is my script pl. In fact, the "line search" line EOF condition is not being obeyed. As a consequence, a violation is occurring in primary key.

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

```
IF TRIM(v_descricao_uo_municipio) = 'Belo Horizonte - Registro de Imóveis' THEN -- id = 2430

  /* Abre o cursor das UO's para inserção */
  OPEN cr_cartorio_uo(v_id_uo_municipio);    
  loop
    Line to fetch: FETCH cr_cartorio_uo INTO v_id_uo, v_descricao_uo; -- Problem is here

    /* Faz carga em "grupodeenviouo" */
    INSERT INTO grupodeenviouo (grupodeenvio_id, uo_id) 
       VALUES (v_returning_grupo_id, v_id_uo);

    EXIT WHEN cr_cartorio_uo%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP cr_cartorio_uo;

END IF;
```

Comment: How do you know that your query is not returning duplicate values?  put some dbms_output calls in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The primary key violation is occurring simply because last row in the cursor is being fetched twice. And the reason why this is happening is misplaced  `EXIT WHEN cr_cartorio_uo%NOTFOUND` statement - it should be putted right after the `FETCH cr_cartorio_uo INTO` statement:

```
if trin(v_descricao_uo_municipio) = 'Belo Horizonte - Registro de Imóveis' 
then 
 /* Abre o cursor das UO's para inserção */
  open cr_cartorio_uo(v_id_uo_municipio);    
  loop
    fetch cr_cartorio_uo 
     into v_id_uo, v_descricao_uo; -- Problem is here

    exit when cr_cartorio_uo%notfound;

    /* Faz carga em "grupodeenviouo" */
    insert into grupodeenviouo (grupodeenvio_id, uo_id) 
      values (v_returning_grupo_id, v_id_uo);
  end loop cr_cartorio_uo;
end if;
```